# SQL query concatenation in C#

Tags: c#

I am doing a nested query (really complicated, don't mind on it). This is the code:

```
sql = "SELECT idGruppo, Sum(qric) AS Qsum FROM(SELECT Gruppi.gruppoDim1, Gruppi.gruppoDim2, Gruppi.idGruppo, Lotti.qric FROM Gruppi INNER JOIN((Lotti INNER JOIN collectTaglio ON Lotti.idLotto = collectTaglio.idLotto) INNER JOIN collectGruppo ON Lotti.idLotto = collectGruppo.idLotto) ON Gruppi.idGruppo = collectGruppo.idGruppo WHERE (((collectTaglio.idTaglio) =" + id + "))) AS gruppo GROUP BY idGruppo";
```

the only parameter is the **int** variabile id.
The string is built correctly, for example with id 1007 in debug the result is

```
SELECT idGruppo, Sum(qric) AS Qsum
FROM
(
  SELECT Gruppi.gruppoDim1, Gruppi.gruppoDim2, Gruppi.idGruppo, Lotti.qric
  FROM Gruppi
    INNER JOIN
    (
      (Lotti INNER JOIN collectTaglio ON Lotti.idLotto = collectTaglio.idLotto)
      INNER JOIN collectGruppo ON Lotti.idLotto = collectGruppo.idLotto
    )
    ON Gruppi.idGruppo = collectGruppo.idGruppo
  WHERE (((collectTaglio.idTaglio) =1007))
) AS gruppo 
GROUP BY idGruppo
```

so the query should produce a DataTable in c# but using the first string the result is empty. 
if i put the built string took from the watch debugger in a full non concatenated string like this the result is non empty (as i expect):

```
sql = "SELECT idGruppo, Sum(qric) AS Qsum FROM(SELECT Gruppi.gruppoDim1, Gruppi.gruppoDim2, Gruppi.idGruppo, Lotti.qric FROM Gruppi INNER JOIN((Lotti INNER JOIN collectTaglio ON Lotti.idLotto = collectTaglio.idLotto) INNER JOIN collectGruppo ON Lotti.idLotto = collectGruppo.idLotto) ON Gruppi.idGruppo = collectGruppo.idGruppo WHERE (((collectTaglio.idTaglio) =1007))) AS gruppo GROUP BY idGruppo";
```

it seems really fun! I am using sql server 2012 and using the same string from sql management works fine.

does anybody knows why? The issue seems only the parameter passing but i can use string built with success. I have tried also with the StringBuilder

this is the querying code (query is a string type):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\db\pporder.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

 DataTable resultQuery = new DataTable();
 conn.Open();
 SqlDataReader leggi = null;
 SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
 leggi = comando.ExecuteReader();
 resultQuery.Load(leggi);
 conn.Close();
 return resultQuery;
```

Comment: this isn't the issue, but: as general advice - you should **really really** avoid concatenating values into SQL; that isn't parameterization. But to repeat: this isn't the issue - still looking

Comment: do you get any exception that perhaps you are swallowing? also: what is the *culture* that the code is running in? is it possible that the `id` to string conversion is not creating the string you think it is? what exactly **is** `id`? how is it defined, and with what value? (side note: if it turns out that it is a "culture" issue, then I must retract my first comment: that *was* the problem, and correct parameterization would have worked correctly)

Comment: id is integer passed from the caller. I don't get any exception. The value is correct and is correctly built inside the string. I tried to copy and paste the built string and used as sql sentence with success.

Comment: so if you do `const string WorkingSql = "...the one that works...";` and check whether `sql == WorkingSql` - does it return `true`?

Comment: then: I suspect that the error is not where you think it is; if the string is the same, it should work the same - maybe double-check everything. Sorry that isn't helpful, but: we can't really repro what you're seeing from here :/

Comment: yes they are the same and it returns true

Comment: I feel for you; that can be incredibly frustrating - it happens pretty much daily for me :)

Comment: What is the data type of `id`? `int`? `string`? Please update your post to include the code that you use to execute `sql`.

Comment: id is `int`, i've updated the post with the code

Comment: Try this . string query = "SELECT idGruppo, Sum(qric) AS Qsum FROM(SELECT Gruppi.gruppoDim1, Gruppi.gruppoDim2, Gruppi.idGruppo, Lotti.qric " + 
" FROM Gruppi " + 
" INNER JOIN( " + 
" (Lotti INNER JOIN collectTaglio ON Lotti.idLotto = collectTaglio.idLotto)  " + 
" INNER JOIN collectGruppo ON Lotti.idLotto = collectGruppo.idLotto)  " + 
" ON Gruppi.idGruppo = collectGruppo.idGruppo  " + 
" WHERE (((collectTaglio.idTaglio) = " + YOUR_INT_VARIBLE + "))) AS gruppo GROUP BY idGruppo"

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens when you pass your int parameter as a SqlParameter? Does it work? (See http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06 for guidance, if you need). And like @MarcGravell said, this would be a better approach :)

Comment: @GaurangDave in this way i have the same results

Comment: @MariFaleiros following that tutorial everything worked!

Comment: @wally oh that's good! Is it okay for you to use this approach, then?

Comment: @MariFaleiros it is really ok for me this approach. Thanks for your precious help (i cannot vote because i don't have reputation but i would like to do it..)

Comment: @wally well, I think I could post it as an answer, for future need :)

Comment: Please can somebody tell me why 2 userse clicked on "minus" and this request has -2 score? I am a newbie and i don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, what happens when you [pass your int parameter as a SqlParameter](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06)? Does it work? And like @MarcGravell said in the comments, this would be a better approach :)